# Объединение команды value_counts со столбцом из dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Коллеги, всех приветствую!
Имею следующий датафрейм с продажами:

```
    product_name    quantity    total_price
2   Номенклатура    Количество  Оплата с учетом возврата
4   Торт Морковный          5           925
5   С Креветками тортилья   4           1596
6   С растительными фрикадельками тортилья  4   1276
7   С растительными фрикадельками тортилья  4   1276
8   С растительными фрикадельками тортилья  4   1276
9   Стакан 0,350            4           80
10  Чай травяной 0,250      4           276
11  Чай травяной 0,250      4           276
12  Чай травяной 0,250      4           276
13  Чай травяной 0,250      4           276
```

Мне необходимо узнать количество продаж каждой продукции, а также сумма, на которую продали позиции.
Общее количество продаж я нашел с помощью:

```
df_1['Name'].value_counts()

Чай травяной 0,250                         284
С растительными фрикадельками тортилья     183
Пепперони                                  102
Коктейль молочный 0.3                      84
С Креветками тортилья                      76
С курицей "Барбекю" тортилья               74
```

А как я могу вывести результат команды выше и сумму на которую продана продукция?
В результате получить хочу что-то подобное:

```
    product_name                         quantity     total_price
Чай травяной 0,250                         284           19596
С растительными фрикадельками тортилья     183           00000
Пепперони                                  102           00000
Коктейль молочный 0.3                      84            00000
С Креветками тортилья                      76            00000
С курицей "Барбекю" тортилья               74
```

Comment: `df.groupby('product_name').agg({'total_price': 'sum')`, вообще почитайте про аггрегации. Там можно сразу и посчитать количество тоже одним вызовом, но без данных сложно написать готовый код.

Comment: @CrazyElf, немножечко не понял вашего ответа. В результате выполнения я получаю общую сумму продажи продукта. А я хочу получить результат где есть общее количество проданного товара, и сумма его выручки.